# Is it possible to customize the features of stack parameter in highchart.js library

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am dealing with a problem with highchart library. On using the stacking = 'normal' parameter I get stacked columns of my column chart. When the values for two inputs are similar I get one graph output line stacked on top of the other. What I actually need is for highchart to print only one of the two inputs(overlapped) when the values are same and not both stacked on top of each other.

Example: Here x1=2 and x2=5. It will plot all the multiples of x1 and x2

**Ideal Output:** 
[image]

**Current Output:**
[image]

Please let me know how can I solve this problem? I don't want those blue lines on top of black line when input is same.

Is there any other parameter for column graph I should look at to deal with the case when inputs are same. I want only one of the output lines to be printed(it is overlapped with the second input).

Here is a JS Fiddle example for the following problem: https://jsfiddle.net/pq82smmb/

```js
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
      },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointWidth: 2,
                stacking: 'normal',
                pointPlacement: 0
            }
        },
    
        series: [{
            data: [{"x": 0, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 2, "y": 0.8},{"x": 4, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 6, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 8, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 10, "y": 0.8}]
        
          }, {   
             data: [{"x": 0, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 5, "y": 0.8},{"x": 10, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 15, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 20, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 25, "y": 0.8}]
        }]
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide some live working example of your problem (jsfiddle, file, URL).

Comment: @KamilKulig  Hi, I edited my question and added a demo example. Please let me know how can I solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by not using stack property at all. Instead I used pointRange parameter and it seems to be working as of now.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pq82smmb/2/

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
  },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointWidth: 2,
            pointRange: 0.05,
            //stacking: 'normal',
            pointPlacement: 0
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [{"x": 0, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 2, "y": 0.8},{"x": 4, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 6, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 8, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 10, "y": 0.8}]

      }, {   
         data: [{"x": 0, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 5, "y": 0.8},{"x": 10, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 15, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 20, "y": 0.8}, {"x": 25, "y": 0.8}]
    }]
});
```